lightning-datatable summer '24 behavior (2 icons in standard cell, edit icon)
We have an extended lightning-datatable in our org that was built by some consultants many years ago. in Summer '24, we had this issue : Behavior of draft-values tag in a lightning-datatable changed in Summer'24
but we also had another issue related to the 'edit'/pencil icon. For some reason, the behavior of the custom datatable prior to summer '24 had the pencil icon always shown for all cells in our component, not just on hover, and our users want the icon back.
We have 2 custom types, which allowed us to insert a combobox into 1 type of cell, and 2 dynamic icons into the other type. The other cell type we use is just the standard boolean type. However the behavior is strange for the boolean type cell because it can have 2 icons in it even now, which doesnt make sense. the standard 'check' is always there, but then we are also inserting a dynamic icon, which shows up to the left of the check icon:
cols.push({
    label: this.productMap[productIds[i]].Name,
    fieldName: `${productIds[i]}`,
    editable: !isFragmented && !quantityOverride,
    type: mapColumnType(quantityOverride, isFragmented),
...
...
    cellAttributes: {
         alignment: 'center',
         class: {
             fieldName: `${productIds[i]}class`
         },
         iconName: { fieldName: `${productIds[i]}icon`}
    }
}

where productIds[i]icon is the 2nd icon that is displayed to the left of the standard boolean checkbox, and the mapColumnType function returns a string, one of the 2 custom types or 'boolean'
so, I'm not sure if this is related to the edit icon, (i have proof that it was showing in the past, not just on hover) but i feel like understanding how this could be happening with the boolean column might get me closer.
so how are we able to use a standard data type but still have 2 icons in a cell?


for whatever it's worth, I did find a hacky way in the CSS to show the pencil icon all the time like I wanted, by targeting it and setting the opacity to 1 in the parent component. But im still confused how 2 icons are appearing in a standard data type cell
